# Relaciones Eloquent en Cliente Laravel consumiendo API REST Laravel

Tags: api, eloquent, cliente, laravel-sanctum, spatie

buenas tardes.

Estoy probando una api laravel con otro cliente laravel.

```
//API - METODO
public function users(){
    $users = User::all();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'usersData' => $users
    ]);
}

//CLIENTE - RETURN VIEW BLADE
public function users(){
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://api-control-visitas.test:82/api/',
        'timeout' => 2.0
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('users');

    return view('users', ['response' => json_decode($response->getBody())->usersData]);
}

//CLIENTE - RESOURCES/VIEWS/USER.BLADE.PHP
@foreach($users as $user)
    <!-- MODEL PROPERTY - SI FUNCIONA -->
    <span>{{$user->id}} - {{$user->name}}</span>
    <br>
    <!-- MODEL ATTRIBUTE - NO FUNCIONA -->
    <span>{{$user->fullName}}</span>
    <br>
    <!-- SPATIE ROLES Y PERMISOS - NO FUNCIONA -->
    <select name="" id="permisos">
        @foreach($user->roles as $role)
            @foreach($role->permissions as $permission)
                <option value="{{ $permission->module }}">{{ $permission->module }}</option >
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```

Usando eloquent se puede acceder a las relaciones del modelo y atributos fácilmente, pero si accedo a la relación, en el cliente, no me permite acceder a la relación.

En mis modelo he creado atributos adicionales, para acceder al nombre completo, estados, fechas, entre otros. Ademas he usado spatie, y al iniciar sesion en la aplicacion cliente quiero hacer uso de las directivas can, para restringir el acceso de acuerdo al rol.

```
@canany(['admin.users.restoration_list', 'admin.users.create'])
<div class="card-header bg-white">
    @can('admin.users.create')
    @livewire('users.users-create')
    @endcan
    
    @can('admin.users.restoration_list')
    @livewire('users.users-restore')
    @endcan
</div>
@endcanany
```

Answer (score 1):

La **API** lo que te devuelve es un `JSON`, osea, una *cadena de caracteres* con la información del `modelo` y no una *instancia* del `modelo`. Es por esa razón que no puedes acceder a ninguna relación ni tampoco a los scopes ni nada que tiene el modelo `User` y en general a nada que esté en el proyecto de la **API** de manera directa.
Lo puedes hacer es en la **API** crear los endpoint para que reciban como parámetro los datos del usuario desde el **cliente** y de esta forma la **API** devuelva la información de las relaciones de los `modelos`.

Answer (score 0):

Para incluir la relaciones en un `json` o un `Array` debes definir el método `toArray()` en tu modelo y agregar una entrada con los datos de tu relación:

```
<?php
class User extends Model
{
    ...

    //Así puedes definir la relación de "uno a muchos" en tu modelo
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rol::class);
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        //Recuperas el array original
        $data = parent::toArray();
        //Agregas la entrada de tu relación
        if ($this->roles) {
            $data['roles'] = $this->roles;
        } else {
            $data['roles'] = null;
        }
        return $data;
    }
 
    ...
}
```

Para exponer tus atributos debes crear la propiedad `append` en tu modelo y pasarle los atributos que deseas "exponer":

```
<?php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $append = ['fullName'];

    //Defines tu atributo
    public function getFullNameAttribute() {
        //Lógica de tu atributo
    }
}
```